# the binomial theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

the Question: Prove the critical Lemma we need to complete the proof of the Binomial Theorem:

i.e. prove $(^{n}_{k})=(^{n-1}_{k-1})+(^{n-1}_{k})$ for $0\lt k\lt n$ (this formula is known as Pascal’s Identity)

you can do this by a direct proof without using Induction.

Any help appreciated, I have no idea what it's talking about

Comment: You know the name of the identity,then why don't you google it?

Comment: ya i did that, and i'm betting copying a wikipedia version of the proof will get me less than 0 points and get me nowhere closer to understanding it

Comment: ,then instead of asking us how to prove a famous identity,why don't you cite the Wikipedia article and point out the specific parts you are having problems with?

Comment: read down below

Comment: See [here]( http://www.brainjammer.com/math/combinatorics).This page should give you some idea about what $_nC_k$ means and where factorials come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Think about what $\binom{n}{k}$ means combinatorially.

Choose any one of the $n$ total elements at random.  There are two cases:  Either the element we have chosen is amongst the $k$-element subset, or it is not.

This method requires far less effort than non-combinatorial proofs, and a complete solution of this form can be found here:

http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/gmacgill/guide/combargs.pdf

Comment: the proofs i've seen use a lot of factorials but they don't say where those factorials come from. I'm guessing there is some identity or something that our professor didn't give us or thought we knew?

Comment: @Mikky Davey,but isn't that how  $_nC_k$ is computed?Anyway,Kaj_H's proof does not require the knowledge of factorials.

Comment: The method I suggest is quite simple and requires no factorials whatsoever.  Simply think about what n-choose-k means combinatorially.

Since this is easily Googled, I will link to a complete solution using my method:

http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/gmacgill/guide/combargs.pdf

Comment: than you! that was extremely helpful

Answer (score 1):

Recall that

$${a \choose b}=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$$

and (for integer a)

$$a!=\prod_{k=1}^ak=a\times(a-1)\times(a-2)\times\cdots\times1$$

Starting from the right hand side

$${n-1 \choose k-1}+{n-1 \choose k}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!}=\frac{(n-1)!k+(n-1)!(n-k)}{k!(n-k)!}\\=\frac{(n-1)!(n-k+k)}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{(n-1)!n}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-1-k)!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k-1)!}\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\right)$

$=\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k-1)!}\left(\frac{n-k+k}{k(n-k)}\right)=\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k-1)!}\frac{n}{k(n-k)}=\frac{(n-1)!.n}{(k-1)!.k.(n-k-1)!.(n-k)}=\frac{n!}{k(n-k)!}$

Comment: thank you for answering can you tell me what formula gives the factorials

Comment: By definition $n!=(n-1)!.n=1.2.3.4.5.\ldots.n$